# Create n number of windows in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a programm in which I am trying to open a n number of windows. My code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Main_window(ttk.Frame):
    """A program"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    """Creates all the objects in the window"""


    self.min_lbl = ttk.Label(self, text = "1").grid(row = 0, column = 0,
                                                    sticky = W)
    self.max_lbl = ttk.Label(self, text = "100").grid(row = 0, column = 2,
                                                    sticky = W)

    spinval = IntVar()

    self.scale = ttk.Scale(self, orient = HORIZONTAL,
                                   length = 200,
                                   from_ = 1, to = 100,
                                   variable = spinval,
                                   command=self.accept_whole_number_only)
    self.scale.grid(row = 0,column = 1,sticky = W)


    self.spinbox = Spinbox(self, from_ = 1, to = 100,
                                   textvariable = spinval,
                                   command = self.update,
                                   width = 10)
    self.spinbox.grid(row = 0,column =3,sticky = W)


    self.go_bttn = ttk.Button(self, text = "Go",
                              command = self.create_windows
                              ).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)


def accept_whole_number_only(self, e=None):
    """Makes the numbers from the scale whole"""
    value = self.scale.get()
    if int(value) != value:
        self.scale.set(round(value))

def update(self):
    """Updates the scale and spinbox"""
    self.scale.set(self.spinbox.get())


def create_windows(self):
    """This function will create all the new windows"""
    value = self.scale.get()
    window_num = value
    negative_window_num = 1
    while window_num != 0:
        root = Tk()
        root.title("This is Window "+str(window_num)[:-2]+" of "+str(value)[:-2])
        root.geometry("350x200")
        app = Window_creator(root)
        root.mainloop()
        window_num -= 1


class Window_creator(ttk.Frame):
    """makes child windows"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    """creates all the widgets in the window"""


def main():
    """Loops the window"""
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Programm")
    root.geometry("350x200")
    app = Main_window(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

What I want this code to do is I want to be able to set the spinbox or scale to number n and then when I click the Button i want n numbers of child windows to appear. I tried this with a while loop but it doesn't quite work like I want it to by creating a new window just after the I closed the prevoius window. You also have to close the main window first for it to work (I am going to make the button close the window automatically later). Any Ideas on how I could make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `child = Toplevel()`, instead of `root = Tk()`.
Also, you can not call `mainloop` more than once (since there should be only one event loop).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Main_window(ttk.Frame):
    """A program"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Creates all the objects in the window"""


        self.min_lbl = ttk.Label(self, text = "1").grid(row = 0, column = 0,
                                                        sticky = W)
        self.max_lbl = ttk.Label(self, text = "100").grid(row = 0, column = 2,
                                                        sticky = W)

        spinval = IntVar()

        self.scale = ttk.Scale(self, orient = HORIZONTAL,
                                       length = 200,
                                       from_ = 1, to = 100,
                                       variable = spinval,
                                       command=self.accept_whole_number_only)
        self.scale.grid(row = 0,column = 1,sticky = W)


        self.spinbox = Spinbox(self, from_ = 1, to = 100,
                                       textvariable = spinval,
                                       command = self.update,
                                       width = 10)
        self.spinbox.grid(row = 0,column =3,sticky = W)


        self.go_bttn = ttk.Button(self, text = "Go",
                                  command = self.create_windows
                                  ).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)


    def accept_whole_number_only(self, e=None):
        """Makes the numbers from the scale whole"""
        value = self.scale.get()
        if int(value) != value:
            self.scale.set(round(value))

    def update(self):
        """Updates the scale and spinbox"""
        self.scale.set(self.spinbox.get())


    def create_windows(self):
        """This function will create all the new windows"""
        value = self.scale.get()
        window_num = value
        negative_window_num = 1
        for n in range(int(window_num)):
            child = Toplevel()
            child.title("This is Window "+str(window_num)[:-2]+" of "+str(value)[:-2])
            child.geometry("350x200")
            app = Window_creator(child)


class Window_creator(ttk.Frame):
    """makes child windows"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """creates all the widgets in the window"""


def main():
    """Loops the window"""
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Programm")
    root.geometry("350x200")
    app = Main_window(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: I recommend *not* calling the child windows "root", even temporarily. I think calling it "root" is confusing since it's not actually the root window.